# Conversion - error E2015 , Ambiguity between AnsiString(char) and AnsiString(short)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++builder

I would like to copy the directory path, which was selected by user, to label (C++ Bulder 6.0)

```
Label->Caption=SelectDirectory("Select a folder:", "", RootDir);
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
E2015 Ambiguity between '_fastcall System::AnsiString::AnsiString(char)'
and '_fastcall System::AnsiString::AnsiString(short)' [C++ Error]
```

Please tell, how to properly convert the result of SelectDirectory function, so I could display it in Label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `SelectDirectory` is a `bool`, not a `String`.  `AnsiString` does not have any constructors for `bool` values, but it does have constructors for `char` and `short` values, both of which a `bool` can be implicitly converted to, thus the ambiguity. Try this code instead:

```
AnsiString selectedDir;

if(SelectDirectory("Select a folder:", "", selectedDir))
{
    Label->Caption = selectedDir;
}
```